# How to set value of closure as function result

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, function, closures

Im stucked. I've tried to find good way to figure out my problem, but I couldn't... So I want to ask you, how can I take value of closure and put it as func result? I want to take data from firebase from different id child. So my func is working- "print(target!)" printing good things, but how can I put it as func result String?

```
    func readID(id: Int) -> String {
    var value = ""
    let ref1 = ref.child("\(av.currentYear())/\(av.currentMonth())/\(av.currentDay())/Shift\(av.shift)/\(id)").child("main").child("id")
    ref1.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot1) in
            if snapshot1.exists(){
                let target = snapshot1.value as? String
                print(target!)
                value = target!
            }
        }
    return value
    }
```

My idea with var value doesn't work, and I don"t want create 10 different variables outside functions. I've wanted try with escaping closures, but I don't understand it yet...

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/returning-a-value-from-asynchronous-code/

Comment: “I've wanted try with escaping closures, but I don't understand it yet” Then understand it. You _cannot_ return a value that is set in asynchronous code, because that would require time to run backward. The line `return value` runs _before_ the line `value = target!`. That’s just a fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func readID(id: Int, completion: @escaping ((String)->())) {
   var value = ""
   let ref1 = ref.child("\(av.currentYear())/\(av.currentMonth())/\(av.currentDay())/Shift\(av.shift)/\(id)").child("main").child("id")
   ref1.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot1) in
        if snapshot1.exists(){
            let target = snapshot1.value as? String
            print(target!)
            value = target!
        }
        completion(value)
    }
}
```

You can get the return value as:

```
readId(30, completion: { 
    [weak self] value in
    self?.text = "This is my \(value)"
})
```

Comment: and how can I add return value to String? For example:
var text = "This is my \(readID(1, comletion: { value in 
value}))"
So I don't want to print it, or add to var, but just read into string. Is it possible? :)

Comment: This is an asynchronous call, so returning normally like a functionalists won't work here. I have edited my above answer for this query.